# errors with multimap (key type is std::string)

Tags: c++, multimap

I've been having problems with getting multimap to work. I'll just show the code and describe the problem:

```
    #include <string>
    ...

    multimap<std::string, pinDelayElement> arcList
    pinDelayElement pde;
    std:string mystring = "test"
    arcList[mystring] = pde;
```

However, when I compile, the last line gives me the following error:

> error C2676: binary '[' : 'std::multimap<_Kty,_Ty>' does not define this operator or a conversion to a type acceptable to the predefined operator
>           with
>           [
>               _Kty=std::string,
>               _Ty=Psdfwr::pinDelayElement
>           ]

Does anyone know something I might be doing wrong?

Comment: ok, I've tried it before (and just tried it again) with
`std::string mystring = "test";
arcList[mystring] = pde;`

and it gives me the same error, so, changing that doesn't fix it

Comment: @Cameron R: Then update your code and compiler error accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code below is an example of how to do it properly.

1. As others pointed out, std::multimap doesn't have the indexing `operator[]` because it makes no sense to extract elements out of it -- there are multiple values per each index.
2. You must `insert` a `multimap<...>::value_type`.

```
#include <string>
#include <map>

void test()
{
    typedef std::multimap<std::string, int> Map;
    Map map;
    map.insert(Map::value_type("test", 1));
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Yeah, it occurred to me after reading juanchopanza's comment that it wouldn't make sense to extract by index the way I was trying to

Answer (score 6):

That is because [std::multimap](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap) doesn't have an `operator[]`. Try using the [insert](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert) method.

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. I had something similar working with map which is why this was confusing for me. I guess it makes sense that it wouldn't be so easy to index with just the key for a multimap. Thanks!