# Why is there no [] operator for std::multimap?

Tags: c++, c++11

Why is there no [] operator for std::multimap?

In [errors with multimap (key type is std::string)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11146442/errors-with-multimap-key-type-is-stdstring), people say "it makes no sense to extract elements out of it -- there are multiple values per each index". To me, it makes perfect sense and this is why there is equal_range.

So, why did they decided not to add a [] operator for multimap then?

I feel it is because things like `myMultiMap[key] = value` would be complex to handle but I am really not sure about that.

Comment: `equal_range` produces a range, not an element. All other occurences of `[]` in C++ produce elements. It would be highly surprising if the operator behaved *differently* in this one case. Instead, you have a consistently named `equal_range` member function that behaves the same for every container.

Comment: Ok. But std::map::operator[] is actually behaving differently. It is performing an insertion when the key does not already exist.

Comment: @Korchkidu Yep it was confusing, i removed it.

Comment: @Korchkidu: Maybe, but consider it this way: `[]` gives you the element at the designated key (map) or index (array). Whether the element had to be constructed first is secondary.

Answer (score 5):

This might be because of ambiguity as **multiMap[key]** can represent many elements depending upon the number of insertion with same key.

The operator[] always returns an **lvalue reference** to the element present at provided index of any randomly accessible container(s), so in case of multimap(s) there will be more than one element for the same key.

**Note** this is not same as the collision in a HashTable based container (std::unordered_map, std::unordered_set) where different keys can have same hash value computed from a hash function causing elements to land in same bucket.